# React Native assemble release warnings

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

Trying to assemble release apk with *gradlew --stop && gradlew clean && gradlew assembleRelease* i get warnings in index.android.bundle:

```
warning: the variable "fetch" was not declared in anonymous function " 429#"
warning: the variable "Headers" was not declared in anonymous function " 429#"
warning: the variable "Request" was not declared in anonymous function " 429#"
warning: the variable "Response" was not declared in anonymous function " 429#"
warning: the variable "FileReader" was not declared in function "b 7#"
warning: the variable "XMLHttpRequest" was not declared in anonymous function " 445#"
warning: the variable "self" was not declared in function "o 20#"
warning: the variable "document" was not declared in anonymous function " 683#"
warning: the variable "requestAnimationFrame" was not declared in function "value 371#"
warning: the variable "navigator" was not declared in function "isStandardBrowserEnv"
warning: the variable "document" was not declared in anonymous function " 683#"
```

and many others

The apk builds well and running on my devices, but app is not working properly (some hooks, fetching requests are not working). But in debug mode all works fine. Can anybody tell me which way to dig?